# Blocking traffic from specific TCP ports to other specific TCP ports using iptables

Tags: iptables, linux-networking

I have a Linux system where I have multiple processes communicating with a master process via TCP ports. I need to create a scenario where I block all traffic from all ports of one particular process to the ports used by master process for communicating with that process.

Example:

- PROCESS A master ports = 1012, 1013 ... 1015
- PROCESS A ports = 2012, 2013 .. 2015

The rule I want to put in is traffic from all ports of PROCESS A (which I can find using netstat etc) destined towards Master process ports is blocked using iptables.

I looked around and found ways of dropping traffic destined to particular ports, but no luck in specifying the source ports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty much the same as with destinations ports. If you used `--dport` for destination ports, you must also specify `--sport` for source port(s)

```
man iptables-extensions

   tcp
   These extensions can be used if  `--protocol  tcp'  is  specified.  It  provides  the  following
   options:


   [!] --source-port,--sport port[:port]
          Source port or port range specification. This can either be a service name or a port num‐
          ber. An inclusive range can also be specified, using the format first:last.  If the first
          port  is  omitted,  "0"  is  assumed; if the last is omitted, "65535" is assumed.  If the
          first port is greater than the second one they will be swapped.  The flag  --sport  is  a
          convenient alias for this option.

   ...
```

Comment: Thanks, however I could not solve the problem as the process that I blocked ports for, opened up new ports to the master process. I am looking to block all traffic from a particular process, up till kernel 2.6 they provided --pid-owner so that we can block out the traffic using pid, but they dont support that on newer kernels. Any ideas about that ? thanks.